# handling data in multiple select option (using $_POST)

Tags: php, mysql

I have multi select field which is come from database. For example my select filed in page (storeform.php):

```
<select name="store[]" multiple="multiple">
<option value=1>Outlet 1</option>
<option value=2>Outlet 2</option>
<option value=3>Outlet 3</option>
<option>.......</option>
</select>
```

I want to get values from the above select field to db using php post and put the values into the Query.This is how I written in other page called (storetable.php):

```
<?php
$storenum=$_POST['store'];
foreach($storenum as $snumber)
{
    //this part i need to get the values and put the values into Query.
    //for example the $storenum hold values $1 and $2, so $1,$2 i need to put in Query.
}

$query="SELECT sum(a.netamt) as netamt, b.store_name,
  c.monusage,c.monusage/sum(a.netamt)*1000 as duh 
  FROM site_sales a JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum = a.storenum 
  JOIN site_salmonusage c ON b.storenum = c.storenum 
  WHERE c.month = '$date211' AND (a.storenum='$1' OR a.storenum='$2') AND a.busidate >= '$date1' AND a.busidate <='$date2'
  GROUP BY a.storenum order by duh"

/* code continue */
```

Comment: I'd just use an [`IN` condition](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php), eg `a.storenum IN (?)` and bind that parameter to `implode(',', $_POST['store'])`. You should probably ensure all `$_POST['store']` values are numeric I suppose

Comment: Are you using MySQLi or PDO to interact with your database?

Comment: thanks. i'd tried your suggestion to use IN condition. and bind parameter to implode. thankyou for your idea. it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some thing like this.

```
<?php
$storenum=implode(",",$_POST['store']);


$query="SELECT sum(a.netamt) as netamt, b.store_name,
  c.monusage,c.monusage/sum(a.netamt)*1000 as duh 
  FROM site_sales a JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum = a.storenum 
  JOIN site_salmonusage c ON b.storenum = c.storenum 
  WHERE c.month = '$date211' AND a.storenum IN ($storenum) AND a.busidate >= '$date1' AND a.busidate <='$date2'
  GROUP BY a.storenum order by duh"
```

Comment: Can't condone an answer that is open to SQL injection

Comment: Thanks Zaid for answering my question. your code working. But how to prevent this code from open to sql injection?

Comment: @AzimAzman please review this to understand SI https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: Hope you modify your query by yourself after reading the article. Or you can use prepared statement by using mysqli or pod connection.